# Cross platform Mobile app development tools with Googleplaygames services

Tags: android, cross-platform, google-play-games, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi i want to build an android app using Cross platform tools.

I want to also use googleplaygames services to submit and display scores to leaderboards.

Can anyone suggest me tools with these features apart from phonegap because i already worked with it?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the popular gaming platforms?  These tend to have good support on all the platforms, and have things like sprite manipulation, physics engines, and other features that are needed for making great games.

As far as Google Play Game Services, there are libraries for iOS and Android which allows these platforms to access the game services.

I'd suggest getting a general understanding of how "native" development works - maybe by looking at the developer overviews in https://developers.google.com/games/services/.

Then check out some of the game engines.  Two very popular ones that support cross platform deployment are:

- Unity - http://www.unity3d.com
- Cocos2d - http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

I am sure there are other frameworks out there, these seem to be the big ones.

Support for Google Play Games for each of them can be reviewed at:

Cocos2d: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/hub/124

Unity:  https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Comment: OK..I've heard that we need to pay for Unity for android and iOS..Is that true and what about cocos 2d?? @Clayton Wilkinson

Comment: unity just changed their license model you can determine what works best for you: http://unity3d.com/get-unity.  I believe for smaller shops they are free.   Cocos2d is open source licensed under MIT license.

Comment: Thanku...Cocos 2d looks promissing....Cant we use googleplaygames services with Appcelerator Titanium?? @Clayton Wilkinson

Comment: I am not aware of an Appcelerator module for play game services, but it would be pretty straight forward to write one.  You might want to check out the Appcelerator community and see if anyone has experience with it (I am curious too!)

Comment: I checked the community.There was a request for the same but no answers provided...How do we write a module for this? @Clayton Wilkinson